# insert data from current month of partitioned table to a non partitioned table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a backup table with partitions called as backup_audit. I need to insert the current month partition data into another non-partitioned table called as audit which has no data. How can we create a sql query to get the current month partition and load to the non-partitioned table?

Here is what I've tried (without success):

```
select partition_name
from dba_tab_partition
where partition_name in (
    select high_value
    from dba_tab_partition
    where table_name='table_backup' and high_value in (
        select to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMM') from dual
    )
)
```

Comment: I tried this, but did not work out

Comment: select partition_name from dba_tab_partition where partition_name in (select high_value from dba_tab_partition where table_name='table_backup' and high_value in (select to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMM') from dual))

Comment: the "high_value" is a LONG datatype (unfortunately).  You'll need to use pl/sql to extract the timestamp you want to compare (pita i know)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to reference partitions to select the current months data. Assuming that your backup_audit table is range partitioned by `audit_date`:

```
insert 
  into audit(col1, col2, col3, ColN)
select col1, col2, col3, ColN
  from backup_audit
 where audit_date >= trunc(sysdate, 'MM')
   and audit_date < last_day(trunc(sysdate)) + 1;
```